# Is this $lastcron variable being evaluated correcty?

Tags: php, moodle

Please refer to this PHP code:
https://github.com/jleyva/moodle-block_configurablereports/blob/MOODLE_36_STABLE/block_configurable_reports.php#L182

Line 182 uses the $DB object to get data from a sql database and then puts the result in the $lastcron variable.

The next line evaluates the $lastcron variable like this:

```php
    if (!$lastcron and ($lastcron + $this->cron < time()) )
```

Please explain this code to me!

Should that if() statement use **!$lastcron** or **$lastcron** at the beginning of the if() statement? In other words, should it be:

```
      if (!$lastcron and ($lastcron + $this->cron < time()) )
```

or

```
      if ($lastcron and ($lastcron + $this->cron < time()) )
```

Comment: With `!$lastcron` it does not appear to make much sense, because then trying to "add" something to any of the values that would be considered false-y, has rather little point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, looks like a bug to me.

`$DB->get_field()` returns false if the record doesn't exist or a value if it does exist.

In this case an `integer` value for `lastcron`

It probably should be an `or`

```
if (!$lastcron || ($lastcron + $this->cron < time()) )
```

Comment: Thanks. I have reported it to the developer:

https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/CONTRIB-8800